# document.location() used for redirection in javascript not working for iOS8.0

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a link shared to some sites, clicking on that will execute a Web API and will

1.redirect by a custom URL schema,
2.That in turn will up my app/ if not installed will display an image.

My problem is that this works perfectly fine on iOS 7, but not working in iOS 8:(
We are using a java script to redirect this document.location () method ?

Any possibilities how I could solve this issue? I was searching for any errors since last one week, no idea about whats happening in iOS 8.0.

I have checked whether custom URL schema working on iOS 8.0 or not, but it worked just fine when I typed directly to browser. So I came to a conclusion that the java script code document.location() used for redirecting not working on iOS 8.0(Assumption). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: QLag, No I didn't get a solution for that. I was doing this for a Facebook post. At last I implemented Facebook app linking instead of this. One of my colleague says he has done something like that. I will check with him and update tomorrow or so.